# Thinkpad t60 crashes

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad

I have a new (to me) thinkpad t60.

Often, if I unplug it while it is running, it re-boots and gives the message, "System has recovered from a serious error".

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

XP Pro SP3, 3 gig ram

EDIT:
I am waiting to have the store where I bought it fix this problem. Scheduling problems have made this take a long time. I will report the solution as soon as I am able to solve it. Thanks for all the responses.

EDIT: I took it back to the retailer to have him try and fix the problem. 
It is his opinion that the IBM power monitor / battery utility is the problem, as stated by Wil, below, and it has been removed. He then had no occurrences of the problem over a period of numerous tests. I am going to do some testing over the next 24 hours and will report what happens.

EDIT: The tech uninstalled the IBM power monitor / battery utility, as suggested and then updated all thinkvantage. His take is that it was caused by the BM power monitor / battery utility, as suggested. It seems fine. Thanks.

Thanks.

EDIT: Well, the store took the T60 14") back. He couldn't stop it from crashing. I have had it replaced with the 15" inch, still have all the software from Thinkvantage installed, and for the last few days have had no problem/. (How do you make the emoticon for fingers crossed? X?

Comment: We have many T60s in the office here and frequently see problems with them freezing or rebooting with docking or plugging in the power.  The docking issue was somewhat resolved by installing insulators on the docking station.  I am wondering if your issue is related to ours.

Comment: It may be although I don't use a docking station.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend had this issue on a T60 when he recently installed a Windows Update.

Uninstall the IBM power monitor / battery utility.

They have not released an update yet. Removing this program fixed the crash on my friend's laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad battery or other hardware fault. Does the laptop work without the charger at all? The error specified is a result of the machine unexpectedly being turned off (usually from sudden power loss or crash) because the Mini-Dump file is written, but the paging file still thinks it hasn't been. You can try the paging file workaround [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317277), but I've heard this problem with laptops a few times before and it's been hardware related mostly.

Comment: if the battery is dead and you unplug it, the machine goes off and that's the end of it. it wouldn't 'reboot'.

Comment: Well, a battery thats completely dead, yes. But one thats "on its last toes" as you would call it, could show these symptoms.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. 

To test your idea, I shut the computer down and unplugged it. I then re-booted it. It booted and showed about 3.5 hours available.

However, I have noticed that the battery virtually NEVER charges to 100%, usually 96-99%.

I never had this on my other laptops.

Comment: The computer has been unplugged for, at the most 50 seconds for this to happen. It has not re-booted on the unplugging but rather when it is plugged in again. Therefore, I cannot be sure that the unplugging is the cause, or perhaps the combination of un- and re-plugging in such a short time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to IBM and getting the newest patches. I was getting a Blue screen on my T42 every so often, as it turns out after a bit of investigation I was having a wireless driver problem. I found this by following the windows error messagebox. I am not saying that you are having a wireless problem just giving a sugestion that you may want to read a bit further into the error screen and perhaps download some drivers from IBM.

Comment: I have taken the computer back to the retailer and had him try to deal with this problem. As a part of the fixes, he did what you suggest.

Thanks